# CodeIgniter Hosting 500 Error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, internal-server-error

I have uploaded my project on a domian `www.abc.com/beta` using CodeIgniter on my localhost server.  Everything is working fine but when I upload it on the server I am getting a 500 server error.

My `.htacess` code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://www.example.com/beta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config file `base_url`,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/beta/';
```

Comment: I think you should read this:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change...

```
RewriteBase http://www.example.com/beta/
```

into this...

```
RewriteBase "/beta/"
```

See:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase